# Eevee Problem with displaying glass (alpha blend)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency, glass, blend-modes

I tried to make glass material following a tutorial and faced with problem when setting to a alpha blend mode
[image]

I have these settings: [image][image] [image]

With Opaque mode it seems fine, but I need to have its transparency

Please, if you know how to solve this problem help me :)
[image]

Comment: Hello, you could disable Show Backface but it looks like there's a problem with the handle? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots hello, thank you for your answer! I tried to remove "Show backface" from the material settings, but is is not exactly that I need. 

I want to make transparent glass with transparent fluid inside

I also pined my project file at the bottom of the question

Comment: light path components you're using are Cycles only: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/light_path.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Eevee, Eevee has some limitations for glass material, also as long as you are in Cycles but in *Material* preview you'll still have some limitations. In Eevee, to avoid bad transparency, disable *Show Backface* for the glass:

[image]

As for the liquid if you want to see it through glass you need to disable *Screen Space Refraction* and make it *Opaque*:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! **That's it!**